# custom segue to implement left panel menu

Tags: ios, swift

I have to implement a left sliding menu, like UBER or Gmail.

I create a custom segue to connect a button to a UITableViewController (the menu), works correctly but i have two problems:

1.- When user touch in any place on the table the content of table disappears

2.- I don't know how to implement the "unwind" when the user touch outside of the table, the idea is write this code only once and not on every view controller.

My StoryBorad looks like this (Very early development):

[image]

and this is my code for segue:

```
import UIKit

class LeftMenuSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        var content = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
        var menu = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        var contentFrame: CGRect = content.view.frame
        menu.view.frame = CGRectMake(-(contentFrame.size.width), 0, contentFrame.size.width/2, contentFrame.size.height)
        var sideFrame: CGRect = menu.view.frame
        var animationFrame = contentFrame
        animationFrame.size.width = contentFrame.size.width/2
        var blackview = UIView(frame: contentFrame)
        blackview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        menu.view.alpha = 0
        blackview.alpha = 0
        content.view.superview?.window?.addSubview(blackview)
        content.view.superview?.window?.addSubview(menu.view)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                blackview.alpha = 0.5
                menu.view.frame = animationFrame
                menu.view.alpha = 1
            }) { (finished) -> Void in
                menu.didMoveToParentViewController(content)
        }
    }
}
```

when running on my iPhone 6 looks like this:

[image]

Comment: you cannot use unwind because you did not make present, but only add menu controller over another controller, you also missed to addChildViewController

Answer (score 0):

For the unwind segue, you will need to create another class subclass of UIStoryboardSegue.

You can create a tapGesture to dismiss the menu and you will need to define this method on your viewController

```
override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {

}
```

You can use this CustomSegue guide: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Instead of creating a left sliding menu, maybe you could use a pod, like this:
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController